# why okta does not redirect back to service provider in SSO case

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, fastapi, okta

i am using open source project https://github.com/jpf/okta-pysaml2-example  for learning okta, saml, sso and flask. i have made the required app integration setting in okta. When i start flast web server as service provider and access http://localhost:5000 using a ngrok, i get redirected to okta login page, where i fillup user/pass. on click submit button , okta lands on https://dev-023456-admin.okta.com/admin/getting-started. however, ideally okta should redirect back to the service provider. what is wrong here? i have configured metadata properly on both the sides. what could be the problem here? how can i narrow down the issue?

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.okta.com/abcdefghijklm">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDqDCCApCgAwIBAgIGAX2Vjf7/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG A1UECAwKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzENMAsGA1UECgwET2t0YTEU MBIGA1UECwwLU1NPUHJvdmlkZXIxFTATBgNVBAMMDGRldi0wMjg4NzY4NjEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJ ARYNaW5mb0Bva3RhLmNvbTAeFw0yMTEyMDcxNTM5NTBaFw0zMTEyMDcxNTQwNTBaMIGUMQswCQYD VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECAwKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzENMAsG A1UECgwET2t0YTEUMBIGA1UECwwLU1NPUHJvdmlkZXIxFTATBgNVBAMMDGRldi0wMjg4NzY4NjEc MBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNaW5mb0Bva3RhLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoC ggEBAIY6Ek4yvOB3pF4+IwAgVYyxdwOXi4AoorFUmgJ1Sv8kLc6SSApwIEKj2N/F8tYDxZKEGcV7 jap8gdYZcLpm4rKfNGw0jjQ+mCT4fcUdzLTsXQ1vzTy+KILvi1Ki3cgzEKt+Oir106XKDCgp+BGc PgGKRQQroxqrUWX12yEGyZ4D7pLt5Pg4SBC9o1xRfP+hK82ev1eO+hmp39pl6QDKPG0tV6FJI/SX bnchBNpGxT2qcMO8LzudQBS9fT7Nu0WPJGRRF/zQdB+ScHvBFnjlTKjEYPwM2yNx5FYMfcZM/qZH jyAocVdAR4LMEOi1jZwlPIgESIyCXYFVptoqm1U+Lh0CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEA c8zc0J0p/oq8zHfVobh0QNov4NUS81iDl0ZcRC3LDJ50X360NPM3q7JRfwVMGGUWs0WNm+km0poa XYzWnZUYbRbeuvXB/lyCjUEVneF3quTpzifffVDO8sl1qosEOFlOPf1NOMiVMwRyBHqWRsbL96E1 TVBK7ezaIa/okXiPm0QflMHV9Sg1HyQHvAxo/topQI3FzrZRehrjol0K0vg29ZiV3Y32Ym2mAWD1 3fV7Fy8QcrbQpZseojkUqqfcIaCAOUtiK+oK86yDTkd6C6Ed5Ib0K7Ckwr0FdZ6w2wo4u+UIAnK+ IOOerfagyzpaT0lAPJ4G55sVX5min7plRDfqfA==</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/dev-02887686_testapp_1/abcdefghijklm/sso/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/dev-02887686_testapp_1/abcdefghijklm/sso/saml"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

sp side config

```
    'service': {
    'sp': {
        'endpoints': {
            'assertion_consumer_service': [
                ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                ("https://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                ("https://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT)
            ],
            "single_logout_service": [
                ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
            ],
        },
        "required_attributes": ['displayName', 'mail', ],
        "metadata_key_usage": "both",
        "enc_cert": "use",               
        'allow_unsolicited': True,
        'authn_requests_signed': False,
        'logout_requests_signed': False,
        'want_assertions_signed': True,
        'want_response_signed': False,
    },
},
 "key_file": "./pki/mykey.pem",       
 "cert_file": "./pki/mycert.pem",
 "xmlsec_binary": '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',        
 'encryption_keypairs': [
   {
       'key_file': "./pki/mykey.pem",
       'cert_file': "./pki/mycert.pem",
   },
],
```

setting in okta

```
Single Sign On URL   http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com
Recipient URL        http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com
Destination URL      http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com
Audience Restriction http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com
```

service provider python fastapi code

```
metadata_url_for = {
    # you can have multiple 'Application Integration' settings in okta and can use here for testing.  
    # key : value (metadata link for 'Application Integration' created in okta)
    'app_integration': 'https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/exk2zsnf574m2JD4w5d7/sso/saml/metadata'
    #'app_integration': 'https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/dev-02887686_testapp_1/exk2zsnf574m2JD4w5d7/sso/saml'
}


# get saml client configuration for a given idP name. Here SAML client means
# Service Provider.
def saml_client_for(idp_name=None):
    '''
    Given the name of an IdP, returns a saml configuration.
    The configuration is a hash for use by saml2.config.Config
    '''

    if idp_name not in metadata_url_for:
        raise Exception("Settings for IDP '{}' not found".format(idp_name))

    rv = requests.get(metadata_url_for[idp_name])  # make http get request with given url and read its response in 'rv'


    settings = {
        'entityid': 'http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com',
        'metadata': {
            'inline': [rv.text],
        },
        'service': {
            'sp': {
                'endpoints': {
                    'assertion_consumer_service': [
                        ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                        ("https://example123.loca.lt/saml/sso/example-okta-com", BINDING_HTTP_POST)
                    ],
                    "single_logout_service": [
                        ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                        ("http://example123.loca.lt/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    ],
                },
                "required_attributes": ['displayName', 'mail', ],
                "metadata_key_usage": "both",
                "enc_cert": "use",
                'allow_unsolicited': True,
                'authn_requests_signed': False,
                'logout_requests_signed': False,
                'want_assertions_signed': True,
                'want_response_signed': False,
            },
        },
        "key_file": "./pki/mykey.pem",
        "cert_file": "./pki/mycert.pem",
        "xmlsec_binary": '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',
        'encryption_keypairs': [
          {
              'key_file': "./pki/mykey.pem",
              'cert_file': "./pki/mycert.pem",
          },
        ],
    }
    spConfig = Saml2Config()
    spConfig.load(settings)
    spConfig.allow_unknown_attributes = True
    saml_client = Saml2Client(config=spConfig)
    return saml_client


@app.post("/saml/sso/example-okta-com")
async def idp_initiated(request: Request):
    print("In idp_initiated....\n")
    key_str = 'app_integration'
    saml_client = saml_client_for(key_str)
    form = await request.form()
    authn_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(
        form.get('SAMLResponse'),
        entity.BINDING_HTTP_POST)

    authn_response.get_identity()
    user = User(authn_response.name_id, authn_response.ava, authn_response)
    request.session["user_name_id"] = str(user.name_id)
    user_store = {'first_name': authn_response.ava['displayName'][0], 'last_name': authn_response.ava['displayName'][0],
                  'user_name': authn_response.ava['cn'][0]}
    # instead of responding with user data. We are redirecting it to home page.
    # resp = JSONResponse(user_store)
    resp = RedirectResponse("https://example123.com/home")

    uid = rndstr(32)
    uid2user[uid] = user
    resp.set_cookie(key='spauthn', value=authn_response.name_id, httponly=True, expires=1800)
    resp.status_code = 302

    return resp

@app.get("/saml/login/example-okta-com")
def sp_initiated():
    print("In sp_initiated....\n")
    key_str = 'app_integration'
    saml_client = saml_client_for(key_str)
    reqid, info = saml_client.prepare_for_authenticate()


    redirect_url = None
    # Select the IdP URL to send the AuthN request to
    for key, value in info['headers']:
        if key == 'Location':
            redirect_url = value

    response = fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(redirect_url)
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'   
    return response
```

[image]

then i land to

[image]

Comment: after you hit your application, are you redirected to Okta's SSO URL for your application? If not, I'd not expect to be returned back properly

Comment: when i hit my SP page it redirects me to okta login page when i put user/pass it redirects "getting-started" page of okta...... where i have to see OKTA sso url?  I have attached SP side confige in the main thread. plz have a look.   moreover can you plz correct the metadata settings in my code?

Comment: When you check your login flow in the browser, the moment you hit your application, and you do not have the session, you should be redirect to Okta SSO URL, which is configured on Okta side as `<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/dev-02887686_testapp_1/abcdefghijklm/sso/saml"/>`. The same setting should be either configured on your app side, or it should be able to digest the config from IdP by metadata URL

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev I have added my service provider code snippet in the main thread where i tried both sso url in SP one by one but none of them worked. can you please look into the code? see app_integration key in  dict  metadata_url_for

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev   I surprised when i copy past the sso url  on browser, it lands in getting-started page of okta after authentication instead of actual okta's app-intergration  url...hence it might not be returning to the SP ....but why?

Comment: which URL do you paste in the browser? Do you see a header above login form on Okta login page saying, that you are trying to log into a specific application?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev I use   https://dev-02887686.okta.com/app/exk2zsnf574m2JD4w5d7/sso/saml/   url.  when i click on this i redirect to okta login page ...that image is attached in main thread.....when i login with google account in okta page i get into gettgin started...that page image is also attached in mail thread ..please have a look

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev do you any idea why is this happening? i have attached snaps in the main thread.

Comment: do you see any SAML payload when you are going to this URL? This request should contain SAML Authentication request

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev  no clicking on  dev-02887686.okta.com/app/exk2zsnf574m2JD4w5d7/sso/saml url  does not send any saml request

Comment: Then I'd say that your application not properly configured on app side, as normally implemented SAML app should send a SAML Authentication Request as a payload

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev is there a way you could verify app side configuration? You can see the xml file generated by OKTA app after setting the config. Is that not enough to debug the fault? any other info you need?

Comment: By app side configuration, I mean actually how your application acts, not the actual XML. But at this point I suggest you to find an available resource, who is a pro in SAML, so that they see the actual flow and figure where the issue is

Answer (score -1):

You are using metadata for idp flow. In idp flow you don't get redirected to SP this way. Use metadata for Sp flow instead which should contain the redirect url pointing to your service so idp can redirect

Comment: https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf

Comment: first  metadata i got from okta setting. Second metadata ie for SP i have just now attached in main thread. can u please pinpoint where the error is. I could not get you as of now. moreover can u plz correct the metadata settings in my code?

Comment: Did you configure relay state before downloading metadata file?

Comment: is configuring relay status is mandatory? as per okta it not. what could we its value if i have to put it anyway ?

Comment: It's value should be the end point where you want to get redirected eventually.

Comment: @ShahidRoofiKhan, RelayState is only relevant in IdP initiated flow. For SP initiated it's not required